# Dependency problem with old version of ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, package-management, kernel

Can't figure this out myself, hopefully someone can help.

Even though I am already on 3.13.0-68-generic, whenever I run an update I get the error message that something is wrong with 3.13.0-58-generic.

(I always have to remove old versions due to lack in disk space in boot - I do always leave the last and the but-last when I remove older ones.)

The exact error would be

```
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic)
 dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
   linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic: 
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic;
    however: Package linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic 
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic
```

`uname -a`

```
olivy-ThinkPad-Edge 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`ls -la /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-*.postinst`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Dez  8  2014 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Apr 10  2015 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Mai  4  2015 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Jun 18 03:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Jun 19 12:05 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Jul  8 05:54 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Jul 29 14:36 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Aug 11 18:19 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Aug 15 01:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Okt  3 01:57 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Okt  7 18:36 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39259 Nov  6 20:59 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Dez  8  2014 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Apr 10  2015 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Mai  4  2015 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Jun 18 03:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Jun 19 12:05 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Jul  8 05:54 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Jul 29 14:36 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Aug 11 18:19 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Aug 15 01:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Okt  3 01:57 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Okt  7 18:36 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   391 Nov  6 20:59 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic.postinst
```

Thank you loads!

Comment: Is this really the whole error message?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: And the output of `ls -la /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-*.postinst`

Comment: Let's try a dirty hack: `sudo touch /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic; sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: It looks like it worked! Thank you SO MUCH, kindest A.B.

Comment: Cool, than accept my answer. I have added a second option and an explanation. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere  in the post-installation script of the DEB package (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic.postinst`) is the code snippet below

```
die "Internal Error: Could not find image (" . $realimageloc
  . "$kimage-$version)\n" unless -e $realimageloc
  . "$kimage-$version";
```

means, the script fails, if `unless -e $realimageloc` returns `false`, or in other words, if the file `/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic` doesn't exist.

---

Two possibilities:

- Create a dummy file

  ```
  sudo touch /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic
  ```
- Run

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```

---

**OR**

- Deactivate the `die` statement

  - Edit the post-installation script

    ```
    sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic.postinst
    ```
  - Search the code block

    ```
    die "Internal Error: Could not find image (" . $realimageloc
      . "$kimage-$version)\n" unless -e $realimageloc
      . "$kimage-$version";
    ```

    and comment the lines out, simply add a `#` for each line
  - You should now see something like this

    ```
    # Paranoid check to make sure that the correct value is put in there
    if    (! $kimage)                 { $kimage = "vmlinuz"; } # Hmm. empty
    elsif ($kimage =~ m/^b?uImage$/o) { $kimage = "vmlinuz"; } # these produce vmlinuz
    elsif ($kimage =~ m/^b?zImage$/o) { $kimage = "vmlinuz"; } # these produce vmlinuz
    elsif ($kimage =~ m/^[iI]mage$/o) { my $nop = $kimage;   }
    elsif ($kimage =~ m/^vmlinux$/o)  { my $nop = $kimage;   }
    else                              { $kimage = "vmlinuz"; } # Default

    $ENV{KERNEL_ARCH}=$kernel_arch if $kernel_arch;


    # die "Internal Error: Could not find image (" . $realimageloc
    #  . "$kimage-$version)\n" unless -e $realimageloc
    #  . "$kimage-$version";

    # search for the boot loader in the path
    my $loader_exec;
    ($loader_exec = $loader)  =~ s|.*/||;
    my ($loaderloc) = grep -x, map "$_/$loader_exec",
      map { length($_) ? $_ : "." }  split /:/, $ENV{PATH};


    ######################################################################
    ######################################################################
    ###########        Test whether a relative symlinkwould be OK #######
    ######################################################################
    ######################################################################
    ######################################################################
    ```
  - Save the file and run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install -f
    ```

Comment: It actually was not this answer that solved my problem, because i tried the advice that he provided in one comment shortly before that. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Yes, that was my comment. And this comment is also included in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, got it :)